# New router has given me crackly audio?

Tags: router, audio

I just purchased the new version of my router from BT, and after connecting it up I began noticing random crackly moments from my computer audio- every now and then becoming so crackly for such a long time I have restarted the program.

I have used a Focusrite Scarlett Solo audio interface for nearly a year but I have never had this problem before.

I connect to my router through wired connection.

It also sometimes gets crackly on opening programs like Chrome.

thanks for any help!!

Comment: It sounds like EMI.  Are you able to isolate the modem on it's own circuit?  If it has any wireless capability you should disable it.

Comment: @Ramhound I use the wireless for other devices so that doesnt sound convenient. Thanks for the help though

Comment: Can you post a sound file of the crackling? I know what it sounds like when Wi-Fi transmissions get picked up on analog audio circuitry, so I could tell you if that's what happening if I could hear the sound. Make sure your audio interface box and analog audio cables (including mic cables, line-level cables, and speaker cables) aren't anywhere near the router. Modern routers transmit at up to 1W of power, and it's easy for that to get picked up by insufficiently shielded analog audio circuits/cables.

Comment: This sounds like a latency issue. Are you using ASIO (guitar/recording etc) when this happens? If so, have you tried raising the buffer slightly?